# Manually register the change password feature in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I wrote a custom admin class for Users in the Django Admin as follows:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    list_display = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'last_login', 'date_joined', 'is_superuser', 'is_active']
    list_filter = ['is_active', 'groups']
    search_fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This breaks the 'change password' feature in the Django Admin. What do I have to add to my custom class to allow it to work again?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted, what error you receive when you try to change the password in dajgno admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit from `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`, rather than
 `admin.ModelAdmin`

Comment: This helped me understand why I had never seen the password reset form link, after having made this error early on in my project while inheriting from ImportExportModelAdmin.